# Adjust parent div height according to inner table height

Tags: html, css

I have a a div and a table inside it. I need to adjust the div height according to the content inside the table which is happening dynamically.

```html
<div class="table-responsive" >
   <table class="table table-bordered" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
          ....
          </tr>
       </thead>
         <tbody>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="searchResult in result ">
          .....
          </tr>
           </tbody>
    </table>
  
  </div>
```

I want to get a vertical and horizontal scrollbar by minimizing the height of the div which happening in Chrome but not in IE9.
Any idea how to attain the same in IE ?

Comment: In what way do you need to adjust the div? Normally divs are as high as their contents, so when exactly do you want the scrollbar to appear? The snippet doesn't help.

Comment: FYI EI10 and below will no longer be supported by Microsoft on Jan. 2015 lol

Comment: @Mr Lister actually I need to add vertical and horizontal scrollbar when no. of rows inside the table is say more than 3.

Comment: @Bidisha I think you need `max-height` and/or `max-width` on the div.

Comment: @Mr Lister that worked in both IE and chrome !! Thanks a Lot !